# Winsock2: how to handle message loop for intermittent sends() called in a dll from a ruby program?

Tags: c++, ruby, winsock2

I'm working on a ruby game client that uses a c++ dll to send and receive data on asynchronous sockets. It is technically [RGSS3](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rpg-maker-rgss3/1.02.0) - not a standard ruby environment - which has no inherent networking or threading capability. Gems cannot be used. So all networking has to be handled in a c++ dll.

The recv() calls are on a thread with a message loop that always runs, but I'm not sure how to handle send() calls.
I call c++ functions using Ruby's win32api, and they run in the same global thread as the ruby program. This thread has no message loop, so I was prototyping by using messageboxes. I accidentally discovered they create their own message loop, which is what was allowing the send() calls to be handled. Without a message box, send() never sends out any data.
This works:

```
(Ruby): 
Win32API.new("Server.dll", "SendData", "P", "I").call(data_stuff)

(C++):
int SendData(stuff) {
    MessageBox(hwnd, TEXT("I make send() work"), TEXT(""), MB_OK);

    int nret = send(s, (char*)stuff, stuff.length, 0);
    return 1;
}
```

But if I take out the message box, my server never receives any data.
I can also stick the send call in a message loop. It doesn't work if the send() is outside the loop, even if it's on the line before. But this works:

```
while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
{
    if (!sent) {
        sent = true;
        int nret = send(socket, (char*)data, data_length, 0);
    }
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
```

However, this seems like a bad solution, since the game is waiting on this dll function to return before it can continue. Also, I don't know how to detect when to exit the loop. I thought about checking the message id and exiting after dispatching a send() message. But I can't figure out the message event id/name that is called for send() to work (if any). Also, the message could be an event for a different send() call.

I can't run a permanent message loop in the global ruby thread which the dll functions are called in. I kinda doubt I should create a thread for each send() call, since there will probably be 5+ per second. I'd prefer to avoid running two different threads with message loops. The best thing I can think of so far would be communicating with the permanent thread that handles recv(), passing it the data to send, and having its message loop check if it should be sending data (or i guess generating an event that would alert it to send data).
But I feel like there's probably a much better way to handle this, and my approach could have all kinds of problems.

I would ideally like the SendData() function to call send() and then immediately return control to the ruby interpreter. I can't figure out an efficient way to accomplish this, or if it's even feasible. Any input as to what approach I should take?

Comment: Delegate the sends to a worker thread that has a message loop, just like your receives are (or even use the same thread). Alternatively, use Overlapped I/O or an I/O Completion Port instead, then you don't need a message loop at all, just a thread to handle the completion notifications

Comment: Thanks, overlapped i/o seems to be a good solution